# Error executing query : While fetching nested row result from mongodb using Presto catalog

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, presto

I have a collection in mongodb that has only one row nested data as mentioned below :

```
db.empnest.find({}).pretty();
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc7d1ec36fc09246097c83f"),
    "class" : "A",
    "id" : NumberLong(45),
    "name" : "Test",
    "tasks" : [
            {
                    "infra" : {
                            "assignee" : "Amar",
                            "status" : "done"
                    },
                    "pocs" : [
                            {
                                    "task1" : "done",
                                    "task2" : "In Progress"
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to fetch this result using JDBC connector for presto using spark java. Below is the code that i am using:

```
//Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        //Open a connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        //Execute a query
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from mongodb.local.emp";
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = res.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        //Extract data from result set
        while (res.next()) {
          //Retrieve by column name
          //String name = res.getString("name");
          //Display values
          //System.out.println(res.getString(""));
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
                String columnValue = res.getString(i);
                System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i) +" : "+ columnValue);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        //Clean-up environment
        res.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
```

But when I run this query, it gives me this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query
at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:274)
at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoStatement.execute(PrestoStatement.java:227)
at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoStatement.executeQuery(PrestoStatement.java:76)
at spark_mongo_poc.SparkMongo.process_query(SparkMongo.java:32)
at spark_mongo_poc.SparkMongo.main(SparkMongo.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error fetching next at http://host/v1/statement/20190430_092905_00031_qxggq/1 returned an invalid response: JsonResponse{statusCode=200, statusMessage=OK, headers={content-type=[application/json], date=[Tue, 30 Apr 2019 09:29:05 GMT], vary=[Accept-Encoding, User-Agent], x-content-type-options=[nosniff]}, hasValue=false} [Error: {"id":"20190430_092905_00031_qxggq","infoUri":"http://host/query.html?20190430_092905_00031_qxggq","partialCancelUri":"http://host/v1/stage/20190430_092905_00031_qxggq.0","nextUri":"http://host/v1/statement/20190430_092905_00031_qxggq/2","columns":[{"name":"class","type":"varchar","typeSignature":{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}},{"name":"id","type":"bigint","typeSignature":{"rawType":"bigint","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[]}},{"name":"name","type":"varchar","typeSignature":{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}},{"name":"tasks","type":"array(row(infra row(assignee varchar,status varchar),pocs array(row(task1 varchar,task2 varchar))))","typeSignature":{"rawType":"array","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["assignee","status"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"assignee","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"status","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]},{"rawType":"array","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["task1","task2"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task1","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task2","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]}],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["task1","task2"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task1","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task2","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]}}]}],"literalArguments":["infra","pocs"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"infra","typeSignature":"row(assignee varchar,status varchar)"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"pocs","typeSignature":"array(row(task1 varchar,task2 varchar))"}}]}],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["assignee","status"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"assignee","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"status","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]},{"rawType":"array","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["task1","task2"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task1","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task2","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]}],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["task1","task2"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task1","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task2","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]}}]}],"literalArguments":["infra","pocs"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"infra","typeSignature":"row(assignee varchar,status varchar)"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"pocs","typeSignature":"array(row(task1 varchar,task2 varchar))"}}]}}]}}],"data":[["A",45,"Niheel",[[["Amar","done"],[["done","In Progress"]]]]]],"stats":{"state":"RUNNING","queued":false,"scheduled":true,"nodes":1,"totalSplits":17,"queuedSplits":16,"runningSplits":0,"completedSplits":1,"userTimeMillis":10,"cpuTimeMillis":1,"wallTimeMillis":2,"processedRows":1,"processedBytes":1,"rootStage":{"stageId":"0","state":"RUNNING","done":false,"nodes":1,"totalSplits":16,"queuedSplits":16,"runningSplits":0,"completedSplits":0,"userTimeMillis":0,"cpuTimeMillis":0,"wallTimeMillis":0,"processedRows":0,"processedBytes":0,"subStages":[{"stageId":"1","state":"FINISHED","done":true,"nodes":1,"totalSplits":1,"queuedSplits":0,"runningSplits":0,"completedSplits":1,"userTimeMillis":10,"cpuTimeMillis":1,"wallTimeMillis":2,"processedRows":1,"processedBytes":1,"subStages":[]}]},"progressPercentage":5.882352941176471}}
```

]
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.$internal.client.StatementClientV1.requestFailedException(StatementClientV1.java:463)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.$internal.client.StatementClientV1.advance(StatementClientV1.java:402)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.getColumns(PrestoResultSet.java:1741)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.(PrestoResultSet.java:118)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:249)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create class io.prestosql.jdbc.$internal.client.QueryResults from JSON response:
[{"id":"20190430_092905_00031_qxggq","infoUri":"http://host/query.html?20190430_092905_00031_qxggq","partialCancelUri":"http://host/v1/stage/20190430_092905_00031_qxggq.0","nextUri":"http://host/v1/statement/20190430_092905_00031_qxggq/2","columns":[{"name":"class","type":"varchar","typeSignature":{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}},{"name":"id","type":"bigint","typeSignature":{"rawType":"bigint","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[]}},{"name":"name","type":"varchar","typeSignature":{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}},{"name":"tasks","type":"array(row(infra row(assignee varchar,status varchar),pocs array(row(task1 varchar,task2 varchar))))","typeSignature":{"rawType":"array","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["assignee","status"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"assignee","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"status","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]},{"rawType":"array","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["task1","task2"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task1","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task2","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]}],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["task1","task2"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task1","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task2","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]}}]}],"literalArguments":["infra","pocs"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"infra","typeSignature":"row(assignee varchar,status varchar)"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"pocs","typeSignature":"array(row(task1 varchar,task2 varchar))"}}]}],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["assignee","status"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"assignee","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"status","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]},{"rawType":"array","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["task1","task2"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task1","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task2","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]}],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"rawType":"row","typeArguments":[{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]},{"rawType":"varchar","typeArguments":[],"literalArguments":[],"arguments":[{"kind":"LONG_LITERAL","value":2147483647}]}],"literalArguments":["task1","task2"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task1","typeSignature":"varchar"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"task2","typeSignature":"varchar"}}]}}]}],"literalArguments":["infra","pocs"],"arguments":[{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"infra","typeSignature":"row(assignee varchar,status varchar)"}},{"kind":"NAMED_TYPE_SIGNATURE","value":{"name":"pocs","typeSignature":"array(row(task1 varchar,task2 varchar))"}}]}}]}}],"data":[["A",45,"Niheel",[[["Amar","done"],[["done","In Progress"]]]]]],"stats":{"state":"RUNNING","queued":false,"scheduled":true,"nodes":1,"totalSplits":17,"queuedSplits":16,"runningSplits":0,"completedSplits":1,"userTimeMillis":10,"cpuTimeMillis":1,"wallTimeMillis":2,"processedRows":1,"processedBytes":1,"rootStage":{"stageId":"0","state":"RUNNING","done":false,"nodes":1,"totalSplits":16,"queuedSplits":16,"runningSplits":0,"completedSplits":0,"userTimeMillis":0,"cpuTimeMillis":0,"wallTimeMillis":0,"processedRows":0,"processedBytes":0,"subStages":[{"stageId":"1","state":"FINISHED","done":true,"nodes":1,"totalSplits":1,"queuedSplits":0,"runningSplits":0,"completedSplits":1,"userTimeMillis":10,"cpuTimeMillis":1,"wallTimeMillis":2,"processedRows":1,"processedBytes":1,"subStages":[]}]},"progressPercentage":5.882352941176471}}
]
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.$internal.client.JsonResponse.(JsonResponse.java:70)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.$internal.client.JsonResponse.execute(JsonResponse.java:144)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.$internal.client.StatementClientV1.advance(StatementClientV1.java:388)

I want to have proper result with the nested array. Please help me

Comment: Where is spark used here? and why don't you use https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/

Comment: I am not using spark-mongodb-connector because I am executing this query using Presto and not spark directly. I want to get the data using presto and then send it back to spark

Comment: When I've seen that error before it was because I was using a JDBC driver that was really old (or really new) relative to my Presto server version.